# Protractor how to get/use the values for one variable from other function

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

```
  it('Check the row count', function () {
   
       module.verifyTableTitle().getText().then(function (Title) {
            expect(Title).toBe('ABC');
          module.verifyexcel().isPresent().then(function (firstExcel) {
              
        downloadex.verifyExcel('Excel1.xlsx'); 
**console.log("rowcount :"+rowObject1");**
}


  this.verifyExcel = function (filename) {
        let workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
        browser.driver.wait(function () {
            return files.existsSync(downloadDirectory + '\\' + filename);
        }, 3000).then(function rowExcel() {
            switch (filename) {
                case 'Excel1.xlsx'':
            let worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Excel1");
                        let rowObject1 = worksheet.rowCount;
                        console.log("rowcount :"+rowObject1);
   });
    return rowObject1;
       });
       break;
```

how to get the rowcount of excel sheet from verifyExcel function(console.log("rowcount :"+rowObject1)) to  top function.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass that variable as argument of top function, example:

```js
const f1 = (arg) => {
    console.log(arg);
}

const f2 = () => {
    let rowcount = "test";
    f1(rowcount);
}

f2();
f1();
```

Comment: If we run f1(); is showing undifined answer. I want to print rowcount inside f1() function.Please guide me.

Comment: @BalaMuruganV this is the most basic task in js, I'd recommend you to take a course of javascript first

Answer (score 0):

declare a variable with `var` or `let` on top of your `describe` block and simply use in any of `it` blocks under the spec.

e.g.- please refer the sample-

```
import { browser } from 'protractor';

var yourVariable

describe('Info API: ', function () {

    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; // for non-angular websites

    it('This is test ', function (done) {

        your code;//use ur variable here
     });

    it('This is test1 ', function (done) {

        your code;//use ur variable here
    });

});
```